# Enable "Access data sources across domains" in IE 11

Tags: cors, internet-explorer-11, accessdatasource

I am trying to enable the "Access data sources across domains" flag in IE11 but it is disabled by default and I am unable to update it. Is there any way I can tweak some registry flag to enable the same.
My objective is to handle the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

[image]

My webpage was initially working fine when accessed via file:///fileName.html on IE, but after deploying the page on server, I am getting the CORS error.

Thanks,
Aakash

Answer (score 0):

On the computer or server hosting the Business Desk client, in Internet Explorer, click Tools, and then click Internet Options.

In the Internet Options dialog box, on the Security tab, click Custom Level.

In the Security Settings dialog box, do the following:
Use this    To do this

Miscellaneous>Access data sources across domains    Select Enable.
Navigate sub-frames across different domains    Select Enable.

Click OK.

In the Confirmation dialog box, click Yes.
In the Internet Options dialog box, click OK.
Close the browser window.

Your computer can now access data sources across domains.